# Split Files based on Pattern search. Split file name with Pattern we searched

Tags: awk

I have a file as shown below:

```
###PSTERS###
LINE1
LINE2
###PSTADS###
LINE3
LINE4
###PSTEEE###
LINE5
LINE6
```

I need to generate 3 files as like (filenames are the pattern we are searching):

PSTERS.txt :

```
LINE1
LINE2
```

PSTADS.txt :

```
LINE3
LINE4
```

PSTEEE.txt :

```
LINE5
LINE6
```

How can I do this? I tried the script below but it is failing with an awk syntax error:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script will take 2 parameters as input.
# 1. Source File Path
# 2. Source File name as input

SOURCE_PATH=$1
SOURCE_FILE=$2

#Get the list of patterns we need to check from the Main source file

cd $SOURCE_PATH
pattern_list=`grep -e '^\#' $SOURCE_FILE | cut -d'#' -f4`
echo ${pattern_list}

#Split the Source File for each pattern in the variable pattern_list

for pattern in ${pattern_list}
do
        cd $SOURCE_PATH
        awk '/\#\#\#'$pattern'/{x='$pattern';next}{print > x;}' $SOURCE_FILE
done
```

Comment: Please read the page on [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to learn how to format your posts.

Answer (score 6):

You are taking a very complicated approach. There's no need for a shell script, this is an `awk` one-liner:

```
awk '{if(gsub(/#+/,"")){name=$0;}else{print > name".txt"}}' file
```

The `gsub` is "global replacement". So, the above means "if a line has any `#`, remove them (replace with nothing), and set the variable "name" to the contents of the line". Since the line will now be everything left over after removing the `#`, `name` will be the pattern. Then, if the line doesn't match a `#` (if the replacement failed), print the line into a file whose name is the current value of `name` and `.txt`.

If you still need the wrapper script, just use:

```
#!/bin/bash -
#This script will take 1 parameter as input: the target file path
targetFile="$1"        
targetDir=$(dirname -- "$targetFile")
targetFile=$(basename -- "$targetFile")
cd -P -- "$targetDir" || exit
awk '{if(gsub(/#+/,"")){name=$0;}else{print > name".txt"}}' < "$targetFile"
```

Comment: @Stéphane Thanks for the edit, useful as always. A couple of questions: i) why the `<`? Are there awk versions that can't open a file? ii) Why get the basename of the file? It should work perfectly well with a full path. Are you thinking of cases where the user gave a relative path instead, so the `cd` would break it?

Comment: Hi i tried the one liner awk command above, but i am getting syntax error as below.

Comment: Error : awk ^ syntax error.. awk ^ unexpected newline or end of string..

Comment: @SreekeshDarshi sounds like you didn't copy it correctly. What exactly did you run?

Comment: i executed the below command

Comment: awk '{if(gsub(/#+/,"")){name=$0;}else{print > name".txt"}}' file

Comment: In place of file i am placing my input file name

Comment: sorry i missed the brace before if command. I added that and the output is charm as expectedthanks a lot...!!!!! The command i used is awk '{if (gsub (/#/,"")){name=$0;}else{print > name".txt"}}' file

Comment: @SreekeshDarshi glad to hear it worked! If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of `relative addressing` of the `ed` editor to pull this off.

Task involves extraction of line number of all the `#` lines in the input file in first pass. Then we generate a series of `ed` commands to get the job done. The right hand side displays the contents of the pattern space as it is molded by the `sed` scrivener

```
sed -e '$s/.*/$/;$q;/^#/!d;=' inputfile |
sed -e '
   N;N;h;                            # p.s.:  1\n###PSTERS###\n4$

   s/^[1-9][0-9]*/&+/; /\$$/!s/$/-/; # p.s.:  1+\n###PSTERS###\n4-$

   s/\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/,\2w \1.txt/; # p.s.:   1+,4-w ###PSTERS###.txt$

   s/#//gp;g;                       # p.s.:   1+,4-w PSTERS.txt

   s/.*\n/\n/; $!D; s/.*/q/
' |
ed -s - inputfile
```